# Is there a way to allocate memory to a container in the toolbox version of docker?

Tags: docker

So I have a container, and to create it in docker toolbox I used:

```
docker run --memory=4096m -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD' -p 1433:1433 -d --name CONTAINER_NAME microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

I have different names and password, but I swapped those out. Every time I run that, it creates, but then exits immediately. When I use:

```
docker ps -a
```

to check on it, under status it says:

> Exited (1) 7 minutes ago

and then when I try to run:

```
docker logs CONTAINER_NAME
```

to check what happened, I get an error saying:

> sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory.

My computer has plenty of ram available, and when I created the container I gave it 4gb of ram, so I don't understand what the issue is here. Also, I cannot use docker for windows.

Answer (score 3):

The fix was to remove the "default" vm that gets created automatically, using:

```
docker-machine rm default
```

and then re-creating it with the command:

```
docker-machine -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 8096 --virtualbox-disk-size "100000" default
```

which gives it 8 gigs of memory and 100 gigs of disk space. Also, renaming it as default keeps Kitematic working, which is a plus.